# Maven shade plugin adding dependency-reduced-pom.xml to base directory

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

The maven shade plugin is creating a file called *dependency-reduced-pom.xml* and also *artifactname-shaded.jar* and placing them in the base directory.

Is this a bug? Should be in the target directory. Any workaround?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can avoid having it created by setting `createDependencyReducedPom` to false.

e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    ....
    ....
</plugin>
```

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom

> **<createDependencyReducedPom>**
>
> Flag whether to generate a simplified POM for the shaded artifact. If set to true, dependencies that have been included into the uber JAR will be removed from the  section of the generated POM. The reduced POM will be named dependency-reduced-pom.xml and is stored into the same directory as the shaded artifact. Unless you also specify dependencyReducedPomLocation, the plugin will create a temporary file named dependency-reduced-pom.xml in the project basedir.
>
> - **Type**: boolean
> - **Required**: No
> - **Default**: true

Comment: If you turn it off, then the thing you build will still have all the merged-in dependencies listed as dependencies.

Answer (score 22):

Based on **bmargulies**' answer and his comment on **Xv.**'s answer, I decided to configure the dependency-reduced POM to be output to `target/`, which is already ignored in my VCS.

To do that, I just added the `dependencyReducedPomLocation` element to the `configuration` element of the plugin, i.e.

```xml
<configuration>
  <dependencyReducedPomLocation>${project.build.directory}/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</dependencyReducedPomLocation>
  (...)
</configuration>
```

Comment: Bevare of this, from the plugin documentation "Where to put the dependency reduced pom. Note: setting a value for this parameter with a directory other than ${basedir} will change the value of ${basedir} for all executions that come after the shade execution. This is often not what you want. This is considered an open issue with this plugin."

Answer (score 10):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-121, and also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-124.

There is an option to move the d-r-p to elsewhere, but you may not like the consequences.

You are wrong about the -shaded jar, it always ends up in target/ unless you move it elsewhere.

Comment: could you explain what should we do with this generated pom ?

Comment: Nothing. Add it to your .gitignore file or set svn:ignore on it. Maven makes it so that it can include it in the shaded jar.

Comment: What do you mean by `You may not like the consequences`? What are the negative consequences?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an old version of the plugin. Version 1.7 of the maven-shade-plugin writes to /target.

Since version 1.7.1, dependency-reduced pom.xml is written to basedir. See the issue [MSHADE-124](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHADE-124) for some reasons why it was done and what the consequences are. If you try setting *dependencyReducedPomLocation*, you will likely run into problems generating the site - open issue [MSHADE-145](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHADE-145).

Answer (score 1):

the documentation on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html is incorrect when it says:

> createDependencyReducedPom    boolean -   Flag whether to generate a
>   simplified POM for the shaded artifact. If set to true, dependencies
>   that have been included into the uber JAR will be removed from the
>    section of the generated POM. The reduced POM will be
>   named dependency-reduced-pom.xml and is stored into the same directory
>   as the shaded artifact. Unless you also specify
>   dependencyReducedPomLocation, the plugin will create a temporary file
>   named dependency-reduced-pom.xml in the project basedir. Default value
>   is: true.

the dependency-reduced-pom.xml is *not* stored in the same directory as the shaded artifact (target directory) ... it is in fact generated in the base directory, not target

Comment: they write (even in your answer you can see): "the plugin will create a temporary file named dependency-reduced-pom.xml in the project basedir"

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the file you can add it to the ignore directive for your DVCS. For `git`, a `.gitignore` file is created with contents:

```
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
```

You can also [add it to `maven-clean-plugin` configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) so it's blown away during the [clean lifecycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference): (Below assumes defaults, such as version, are defined in the [POMs `pluginManagement` section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management).)

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>.</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/dependency-reduced-pom.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Note that the above configuration is additive to the non-customized clean default.