# What is `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` file which created when calling maven package command?

Tags: maven, dependencies, package, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

I'm following maven tutorial from springsource [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx4ei.png), and after 1) adding `joda-time` dependency  , and 2) calling `mvn package` commmand, we get the below file `dependency-reduced-pom.xml`.

My question is, what is the purpose of creating this file besides `pom.xml` file?

[image]

Comment: I guess you are using the maven-shade-plugin? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom

Comment: Yeah, it is. The tutorial use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven shade plugin adding dependency-reduced-pom.xml to base directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314182/maven-shade-plugin-adding-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-to-base-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of dependency-reduced-pom.xml generated by the shade plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904573/what-is-the-purpose-of-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-generated-by-the-shade-plugin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set to true the flag `createDependencyReducedPom` (by default is true), the **dependencies** that have been **included** into the uber JAR will be **removed** from the `<dependencies> section` of the generated POM.

The reduced POM will be named *dependency-reduced-pom.xml* and is stored into the same directory as the shaded artifact.

Unless you also specify `dependencyReducedPomLocation`, the plugin will create a temporary file named *dependency-reduced-pom.xml* in the project basedir.

Extracted from here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom

[image]

Comment: So that means when the dependencies are in the .jar already, we don't have to mention them in the to-be application `pom.xml` right i.e. `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` will be used as pom.xml?

Comment: I think that, that is a another question and maybe should be in another thread. But as I understand, I would work in the original pom.xml and I would avoid the dependency reduced pom (createDependencyReducedPom to false)

Comment: How do you set the `createDependencyReducedPom` to false?

Answer (score 2):

copied from [What is the purpose of dependency-reduced-pom.xml generated by the shade plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904573/what-is-the-purpose-of-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-generated-by-the-shade-plugin):

> Well, if you have a module A with X dependencies, and shade some of
>   them in a specific JAR (A-shaded.jar), then you won't need those
>   shaded dependencies if you want to depend on A-shaded.jar instead of
>   A.jar. So the plugin creates a pom.xml containing only the Y
>   non-shaded dependencies.