# Is dependency-reduced-pom.xml automatically used instead of pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

Is `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` created by [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) **automatically** used in projects that depends on the uberjar (instead of the ordinary `pom.xml`)?

Asking this after reading a number of dependency-reduced-pom.xml related questions and haven't found the answer yet:

[Maven shade plugin adding dependency-reduced-pom.xml to base directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314182/maven-shade-plugin-adding-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-to-base-directory)

[What is the purpose of dependency-reduced-pom.xml generated by the shade plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904573/what-is-the-purpose-of-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-generated-by-the-shade-plugin)

[What is `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` file which created when calling maven package command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500735/what-is-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-file-which-created-when-calling-maven-packa)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` is generated at build time into `${basedir}` of the project. This file is a temporary file that is only used for packaging into the shaded jar. Quoting the documentation of the [`createDependencyReducedPom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom) attribute:

> Flag whether to generate a simplified POM for the shaded artifact. If set to `true`, dependencies that have been included into the uber JAR will be removed from the `<dependencies>` section of the generated POM. The reduced POM will be named `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` and is **stored into the same directory as the shaded artifact**. Unless you also specify `dependencyReducedPomLocation`, the plugin will create a **temporary file** named `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` in the project basedir.

To make it clear, after the `maven-shade-plugin` has run:

- your initial POM will be left unchanged;
- a temporary file that you can completely ignore named `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` will have been generated inside the root folder ([this is considered an open issue with this plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#dependencyReducedPomLocation));
- the shaded artifact will contain your initial POM unchanged inside the `META-INF` directory and not the reduced POM (this is not really important but better mention it - there was an issue about this that was closed automatically: [MSHADE-36](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-36));
- the POM that will be deployed is the reduced POM;
- the shaded artifact will be by default the main artifact of the project.

Comment: Thanks, and I wondered where your answer disappeared :) Couple of points yet not clear: 1) If it's *temporary* file, why it's not deleted afterwords? 2) So, the answer is NO? Because of the MSHADE-36 issue you mentioned? 3) If MSHADE-36 got fixed and dependency reduced pom will to replace the packaged pom.xml, the answer will become YES? :)

Comment: 1) No idea. I guess it could be deleted, yes. I couldn't find an issue about this. 2) & 3) Actually the POM inside the META-INF folder is just informatory so it's not really important that it's not the reduced POM. Whay is important is that the deployed POM will be the reduced POM. So if you depend on the shaded artifact, you will depend on the reduced POM (that will effectively replace the "initial" POM).

Comment: @Tunaki The issue [MSHADE36](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-36) has been closed after 4 years of no interest..(No voting / no comment etc.) ..What do you think? Reopen it ? Offer a patch for it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'll see if I can reproduce the issue (because I made a first test and weirdly enough I didn't reproduce it -- maybe it was fixed in the mean time but wasn't traced in a bug report)

Comment: MSHADE-36 was implemented as the property `useDependencyReducedPomInJar`