# maven reference jar with dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, maven-metadata

In the maven build with Teamcity, maven-metadata.xml has this difintion, then I want to reference the jar-with-dependencies, it always gave me the version without dependencies. Not sure the problem is the maven or Teamcity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.aa</groupId>
  <artifactId>bb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20161213.151229</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>5</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20161213151229</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20161213.151229-5</value>
        <updated>20161213151229</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20161213.151229-5</value>
        <updated>20161213151229</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0-20161213.151229-5</value>
        <updated>20161213151229</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So did you specify `<classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>`? Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: thank, I added classifier,  jar-dependencies is downloaded. but the issue is, the referenced jar still downloaded. I want to create a fat jar to avoid downloading each jar and then avoid conflicts.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the `maven-shade-plugin` instead to create your fat JAR. It will reduce your POM and make sure the deployed POM doesn't have the dependencies that are included in the far JAR. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35155294/1743880