# What would be a reason to set createDependencyReducedPom to false (maven-shade-plugin)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I've read a number of sources regarding the `createReducedDependencyPom` of the `maven-shade-plugin`:

- [Is dependency-reduced-pom.xml automatically used instead of pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154717/is-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-automatically-used-instead-of-pom-xml?rq=1)
- [What is the purpose of dependency-reduced-pom.xml generated by the shade plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904573/what-is-the-purpose-of-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-generated-by-the-shade-plugin)
- [Maven shade plugin adding dependency-reduced-pom.xml to base directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314182/maven-shade-plugin-adding-dependency-reduced-pom-xml-to-base-directory)
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom

I understand it will create a pom with the dependencies that were shaded removed, so as downstream dependencies on the shaded jar would not process again those dependencies that are accessible from the shaded jar.

Yet, I can't understand **in which situation one would change the default value (true) to false**.

Can anyone provide an example of when this is useful?

Comment: Maybe overriding the value via a property, which would be dependant on different factors, e.g. if it's a testing environment for debugging etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While having `createDependencyReducedPom` set to `true` is useful when using the shaded artifact (jar) as a dependency for other projects, I have recently encountered an issue where running my multi-module maven build in parallel with more than 1 thread would cause the `maven-shade-plugin` to go into an infinite loop and block the build forever.

Disabling the creation of `dependency-reduced-pom` files is the way to get around that issue for me.

Another reason why you wouldn't want to create `dependency-reduced-pom` is when the shaded jar being built is an application and not a library to be resued elsewhere.